# How to change geometry color on click in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js. I found an example on the official website. I want to change the color of geometry by clicking the button. How can I do this? I tried to use the mouse click event to do it, but it was useless.

```
function init(){

......
......
......
  $("red").onclick(function (e) {
            rollOverMesh.material.color=0xff3333;
        });

}
```

Comment: In my answer here you can see objects changing colors on click: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278137/how-to-select-and-highlight-multiple-objects-with-rectangular-selection-ribbon/55285698#55285698

Comment: You might also find it useful to update objects on mouse hover: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873977/re-render-object-on-mouse-hover/54240704#54240704

Comment: for insights you may also inspect my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/av1rnh3j/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rollOverMesh is a Mesh. Please try

```
var onClick = function() {
  rollOverMesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff * Math.random());
  rollOverMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
};

$('red').click(onClick);
```

If you want to change material in live scene, you must set material again.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkr1gc4e/

Comment: same result after trying

Comment: @a1lenyang Updated answer with live update. Could you please check now.

Comment: My reference example is this：https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter

Comment: You don't have to set material again, and no need of needsUpdate

Comment: The above code changes all geometry into another color, but what I want is to change the color of the next geometry I add instead of all objects. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set color like this :

```
rollOverMesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff3333);
```

Comment: But where do I put it?

Comment: `
 $("red").onclick(function (e) {
        rollOverMesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff3333);
        
    });
init();
render();
`